# Select range of cells with same value and elaborate

Tags: vba, excel, cells

I'm new with VBA, and I'm trying to elaborate some data from experiments.

Briefly, I have 2 columns, A and B.
In column A numbers 0 and 2 are repeated many times, such as " 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0". The number of repetition is not constant. My final aim is to do the mean of the numbers in column B corresponding to a range of continuous 0s or 2s in column A. In other words my purpose is to have an automatic procedure which begins from the first data of column A, defines a range of cells with the same value, and does the mean of the corresponding cells on the right. And then goes on with the next range.

This is my code:

```
Sub do_mean()

Dim myrange As Range
Dim first_cell As Range
Dim last_cell As Range
Dim mean_cell As Range
Dim n As Long
Dim j As Integer

Set first_cell = Cells(1, 1)

Do While Cells(j, 1).Value <> ""

If first_cell.Value = 0 Then
    For i = 0 To 10
    If first_cell.Offset(i, 0).Value = 2 Then
        Set last_cell = first_cell.Offset(i - 1, 0)
        n = i
        Exit For
        End If
    Next i
Set myrange = Range(first_cell, last_cell).Resize(1)
Set mean_cell = first.cell.Offset(3)
    mean_cell.Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=average(myrange)"
End If
 Set first_cell = last_cell.Offset(, 1)

 j = j + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Please note that the code is incomple, because when i try to run it, RunTime Error 1004 occurs ("Application-defined or object-defined error"), so i stopped.

Any help and suggestions will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: you have an errant `.` in this line: `Set mean_cell = first.cell.Offset(3)` it should be: `Set mean_cell = first_cell.Offset(3)`

Comment: BTW: this can be done with this formula: `=IF(A1<>A2,AVERAGE(INDEX(B:B,IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($A$1:A1)/($A$1:A1<>A1),1),0)+1):INDEX(B:B,ROW())),"")` in the row 1 of the output column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited** after OP's further request in comment

you could use `AutoFilter()` method and `Areas()` property of `Range` object:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    With Range("A1", cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<--| reference column A cells from row 1 (header) down to last not empty one
        GetMean .cells, 0
        GetMean .cells, 2
    End With
End Sub

Sub GetMean(rng As Range, val As Long)
    Dim area As Range

    With rng '<--| reference passed range
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=val '<--| filter cells with passed value
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .cells) > 1 Then '<--| if any filtered cells other than header
            For Each area In .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).areas '<--| loop through each 'Area' i.e. each range of contiguous filtered cells
                area.cells(1).Offset(, 2) = WorksheetFunction.Average(area.Offset(, 1)) '<--| write the mean of cells in the next column of current 'area' two columns to the right of first 'area' cell
            Next
        End If
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False '<--| prevent Excel UI to ask you about overwriting cells
        .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1, 2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlUp '<--| select referenced range offset two columns to the right blank cells and delete them 
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True '<--| restore default Excel alert displaying
    End With
End Sub
```

just be sure your first row is a "header" one

Comment: Thank you all very much,
the code works perfectly!!! You're the best! 
:D I'm so happy!

Comment: Just one last thing,
how can I report the means all in one column? Instead of writing them next to the current "area", I'd like to write them sequentially without spaces..

Comment: You are welcome. Since my answer solved you _original_ question you might want to mark it as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. As for your _furher_ issue, you may want to add some more info

Comment: I accepted you answer, thank you again.
About my last issue, i'd like to write the mean of cells in the column without blank cells within them, one under the other!